# Get attributes of use element that are defined by defs element with snap.svg

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I'm new to svgs and brand new to snap.svg. I'm working on generating elements within an SVG and have the following to work with:

```
<svg width="600" height="400" style="shape-rendering: geometricPrecision; position: absolute;
        left: 0; top: 0;">
        <defs>
            ...
            <circle id="dot" r="10" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

I want to use javascript to create mutliple instances of the circle `#dot` at different positions. So I have some javascript using snap.svg like this:

```
var dot = svg.use("dot");
var r = dot.attr("r");
dot.attr({ x: shapeData.X-r, y: shapeData.Y-r, class: "dot" });
```

but the value I'm getting for the radius, `r`, is null. How can I access values describing my circle like, r, width, height, fill color, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way use elements work in SVG is they are basically just pointers to the original object. If you place a clone of that dot on the canvas with use, the clone doesn't have a defined radius. It points back to dot, which has a defined radius.

It's not entirely clear to me what all you need to do but I think the right way to approach this is to get a reference to dot that you can then use for this purpose. You can clone dot and add other attributes to it later.

Aside from that you're just missing a lot of Snap stuff you need but maybe that's because you're just giving us a snippet.

Here's some code:

```
<svg id="svg" width="600" height="400" style="shape-rendering: geometricPrecision; position:absolute;left: 0; top: 0;">
<defs>
  <circle id="dot" r="10" stroke-width="2"></circle>
</defs>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
// reference to svg
var svg=Snap('#svg')

// reference to dot, stored in a
var a=svg.select('[id="dot"]')

// what's the radius of a?
var r=a.attr('r')
alert('The radius is '+r)

// clone a and add it to the svg
b=a.use()
svg.append(b)

// give b some attributes
b.attr({x:100,y:50})
console.log(b.attr())
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ksy7mLsx/1/